# Show that $2^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ without using induction

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-coefficients

Show that $2^n>\frac{(n-1)n}{2}$ without using induction.

MY attempt :

$$1+2+3+...+(n-2)+(n-1)=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

Since $2^n>n$,

$$2^n+2^n+2^n+...+2^n+2^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

$$(n-1)2^n>\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$$

SO I'm getting an obvious fact :(

How to do it without induction?

Comment: You have a stronger inequality $2^n\ge \frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$ for all integers $n\ge0$.  The equality cases are $n=0,1,2$.  The subset-counting argument by integrand can be used to prove this.  For $n\ge 5$, you even have $2^n\ge n^2+n+2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint** For $n \geq 2$ you have:

$$2^n=(1+1)^n= \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} > \binom{n}{2}$$

Comment: It's worth it for the reader to compare this answer with integrands answer.

Comment: @fleablood I actually liked Integrand answer more, I would had chosen it. It is also worth pointing that the binomial theorem is typically proven by induction, so induction is actually hidden here, but Integran's answer does not really use induction.

Comment: But.... it's always and interesting issue to me... is it kosher to do a proof by practical applications.  In high school it we hard for me to iron all the details of proving the product of $n$ consecutive integers is divisible by $n!$ (each of he $k:1\le k\le n$ will divide one of the consecutive integers... but what if two divided the same one... then you have to deal with gcds and primes and... tedious). But as the answer to the number of ways to choose $n$ items from $n+k$ *had* to be the product of $k+1$ to $n+k$ divided by $n!$ that *had* to be an integer... that still feels.... cheating.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose you have a finite set of $n$ elements. $2^n$ is the number of all possible subsets. $n(n-1)/2$ is the number of subsets of size exactly two, which is strictly less than the number of all possible subsets.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray}
2^0 &\geq& 1 \\
2^1 &\geq& 2 \\
2^2 &>& 3 \\
&\vdots& \\
2^{n-1} &>& n-1 \quad \text{for } n>1 \\
\end{eqnarray}
If you add everything up, you get (for $n>1$):
$$
2^n -1 = 2^0+2^1+...+2^{n-1} > 1+2+3+...+(n-1) = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
which means that for $n>1$
$$
2^n > 1+\frac{n(n-1)}{2} > \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$
We can manually check that this inequality also holds for $n=1$

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use "well known facts"

WKF1:  $2^n - 1=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$.

WKF2:  $\frac {n(n-1)}2 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k$

WKF3: $2^k > k$

WKF4:  $b_k > a_k$ then $\sum_{k=0}^n b_k > \sum_{k=0}^n a_k$.

So ... $2^n> 2^n-1 =\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k > \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} k = \frac {n(n-1)}2$.

....

But.... I'm not sure I'd call that a "proof without induction" as the WKFs were taken for granted without proofs and, most likely, to prove them one would have used induction.